# How can I draw sectors by lon/lat (for each record) in a table

Tags: arcobjects

I found some short code in the net (Sub CreatePie and Sub CalLine) that draw only for one point. I want to draw many point, so I make a table Temp.tab with 4 columns: Cellname, Lon, Lat, Azimuth

I want to draw sector for each Lon/Lat and each sector with a different colour, but it took more than 40 minutes to do that, and the colour is not correct.

Can you help me to correct the code below?

```
Create Table Sectors (id Char(10)) file Trash TYPE NATIVE Charset "WindowsLatin1"
Create Map For Sectors CoordSys Earth Projection 1, 0

Fetch First From Temp
Do While Not EOT (Temp)
'---Cell 1 ------
Lon1=Temp.Longitude
Lat1=Temp.Latitude
Bearing1=Temp.Azimuth
Beam1=60
Dist1=0.3
CALL CreatePie(Lon1, Lat1, Bearing1, Beam1, Dist1, Brush1, Pen1)

'----Cell 2 ------
Fetch Next From Temp
Lon2=Temp.Longitude
Lat2=Temp.Latitude
Bearing2=Temp.Azimuth
Beam2=60
Dist2=0.3

CALL CreatePie(Lon2, Lat2, Bearing2, Beam2, Dist2, Brush2, Pen2)

'---Cell 3 --------
Fetch Next From Temp
Lon3=Temp.Longitude
Lat3=Temp.Latitude
Bearing3=Temp.Azimuth
Beam3=60
Dist3=0.3
CALL CreatePie(Lon3, Lat3, Bearing3, Beam3, Dist3, Brush3, Pen3)
Fetch Next From Temp
Loop

End If


 '---------------------------

HandleError:
Note Error$()

End Sub SelectTableAndColumn
' ==========================================================================

SUB CreatePie(x as Float,y as Float,Brg as float,Ang as float,Dst as float,aBrush as brush,aPen as Pen)
dim sAng as float
dim eAng as float
dim Cntr as integer
dim NewArc as Object
dim Pnts as integer
dim IncVal as float
dim rTemp as float
dim DMS as float
dim aRow as float
dim cnvt as float 

Set ProgressBars OFF

Set ProgressBars OFF
'>>>> SET DISTANCE UNIT TO uDIST > "mi" "km" "m" "ft"
'Set Distance Units "km"
'Set Map Distance Units "km"

'>>>> CREATE A TEMP TABLE TO BUILD OBJECTS <<<<

if Ang=0 or Ang=360 then ''' OMNI-DIRECTIONAL
  aObj=CreateCircle(x,y,Dst)
  Alter Object aObj Info Obj_Info_Brush , aBrush
  Alter Object aObj Info Obj_Info_Pen , aPen
  insert into Cosmetic1 (Obj) Values (aObj)
exit sub
else
  sAng=brg-(Ang/2)
  eAng=Brg+(Ang/2)
end if

while sAng<0 
  sAng=sAng+360
wend
while sAng>360
  sAng=sAng-360
wend
while eAng<0
  eAng=eAng+360
wend
while eAng>360
  eAng=eAng-360
wend
Pnts=Fix(Ang)
if Pnts=0 then
   NOTE "CAN NOT HAVE '0' ANGLE [points]"
exit sub
End IF
IncVal=Ang/Pnts
rTemp=0
DMS=sAng

Call CalcLine(x,y,sAng,Dst)
insert into Sectors (obj) values (aobj)
Create PLine into Variable NewArc 0
Alter Object NewArc NODE Add (sx ,sy)
DMS=DMS+IncVal
do
   Call CalcLine(x,y,DMS,Dst)
   Alter Object NewArc NODE Add (sx ,sy)
   rTemp=rTemp+IncVal
   DMS=DMS+IncVal
Loop Until rTemp>=Ang
insert into Sectors (obj) values (NewArc)
Create Line into variable aObj (x,y) (sx,sy)
insert into Sectors (obj) values (aObj)
select * from Sectors into Sel
Objects Combine
fetch last from Sectors
aObj=Sectors.obj
aObj=ConvertToRegion(aObj)
Alter Object aObj Info Obj_Info_Brush , aBrush
Alter Object aObj Info Obj_Info_Pen , aPen


End sub

'==============================================================

SUB CalcLine(cx as float, cy as Float, degree as float, fLength as float)

define DegDist 69.0932915 '' miles a zero lat per lon
define deg2Rad 0.01745329252
define rad2deg 57.29577951

dim x, y as Float

while Degree>360  ''' make bearing 0 to 359.999999999------
  Degree=Degree-360
wend
while Degree<0
  Degree=Degree+360
wend
if Degree=0 or Degree=360 then
  Y = CY + ( ( (cos(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  / DegDist ) )
  X = CX
elseif (Degree > 0) and (Degree < 90) then
  Y = CY + ( ( (cos(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  / DegDist ) )
  X = CX + ( ( (sin(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  /(DegDist * cos(cy*Deg2Rad))) )
elseif (Degree = 90) then
  Y = CY 
  X = CX + ( ( (sin(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  /(DegDist * cos(cy*Deg2Rad))) )
elseif (Degree > 90) and (Degree < 180) then
  Y = CY + ( ( (cos(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  / DegDist ) )
  X = CX + ( ( (sin(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  /(DegDist * cos(cy*Deg2Rad))) )
elseif (Degree = 180) then
  Y = CY + ( ( (cos(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  / DegDist ) )
  X = CX
elseif (Degree > 180) and (Degree < 270) then
  Y = CY + ( ( (cos(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  / DegDist ))
  X = CX + ( ( (sin(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  /(DegDist * cos(cy*Deg2Rad))) )
elseif (Degree = 270) then
  Y = CY
  X = CX + ( ( (sin(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  /(DegDist * cos(cy*Deg2Rad))) )
elseif (Degree > 270) and (Degree < 360) then
  Y = CY + ( ( (cos(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  / DegDist ) )
  X = CX + ( ( (sin(Degree * Deg2Rad) * fLength)  /(DegDist * cos(cy*Deg2Rad))) )
end if

aObj=CreateLine(cx,cy,x,y)
sx=x
sy=y
END SUB
```

Comment: I'm just not seeing this as an ArcMap or Python problem so I am removing those tags - which product(s)/component(s) from the ArcGIS platform are you trying to use?  I'm thinking it must be ArcObjects.  In any event, please **edit** that detail into the body of your question.